# how to get value in input balise

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

good evening, I would like to get the number 6355 in the balise below:

```
<div class="submitContainer txtC"><input class="btnRed bold" type="submit" value="Rechercher (6 355 annonces)"/></div>
```

This is the code that I use and I need help for the variable pagination:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL_accueil = "https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?mileageMax=150000&priceMax=17000&priceMin=5000&yearMin=2012&age=1"
page_accueil = requests.get(URL_accueil, headers={'User-Agent': str(UserAgent().chrome)})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_accueil.text, "lxml").find('div', {"class": "submitContainer txtC"})
print(soup)
print("\n\n")
try:
    pagination = soup.find('input', {"type": "submit"}).text()
except Exception:
    pagination = "missing"
print(pagination)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things jump out as wrong with your code.

1. in the line:

   ```
   pagination = soup.find('input', {"type": "submit"}).text()
   ```

   `text` is a value not a method attempting to call it will send your code to the except route.
2. It is not 'text' you want as an input of type submit won't usually have any. You say you want to pick up the number in the value attribute of the input tag. The first stage in doing that is to change the line above to:

   ```
   pagination = soup.find('input', {"type": "submit"})["value"]
   ```